# Authorize.net CIM - prefilled the billing info while adding the customer payment profile

Tags: php, authorize.net

i am creating customer payment profile in Authorize.net (CIM) through the authorize.net interface and i want to show the billing address as prefilled. So is there any way to pass data while adding the customer payment profile

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the hosted forms (iframes) or the API?

If you're using the hosted forms, there's no way currently to prefill billing info on the AddPayment form. You can get pre-filled billing address if you use the ManageShippingPayment form, but customer has to click "Add Payment", which doesn't work too well for a checkout page.

I've left a suggestion on authorize.net's forums and an admin said she's relayed the request to their developers, so hopefully sometime they will have a fix.

In the meantime, check out CREsecure. They do basically the same thing but offer an iframe payment form that works good.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit dated, but in all reality PCI compliance forbids the billing address from being stored or transmitted on or from your server.

So any semblance of autofilling would be for what purpose?